# Unable to remove lines/vertex points

Tags: modifiers, faces

I made a grate by creating a cylinder then removing the center portion by boolean operations using another cylinder.  I then created a face on the top of the cylinder, and an array of cubes which I then superimposed on top of the cylinder and removed portions of the cylinder face using boolean operations again.  This had the effect of created a grate. But, this created some weird lines/vertexes/faces that I cannot merge.  Here's a screenshot of the top of the grate.  I've highlighted the lines I want to remove.  Apologies if this doesn't make sense, as I've got a dumb headache.

How do I get rid of the lines/vertexes/faces?  I'm needing to bevel the outside edge and I can't do it unless I get rid of them.

Thanks[image]

Comment: It's a result of the boolean operation. Blender can't "poke holes" in the middle of a mesh - it must have adjoining edges to facilitate the cut. Though you can control how the boolean is placed by preparing your topology, in most cases, you place the "cutter object" and let blender figure out the rest. The problem with this is that it a) often leaves "ugly" topology, and b) creates its own adjoining edges that cannot be removed until proper topology is re-established. This would be accomplished largely in your case by connecting all of the verts in the intersections of the "bars".

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to propose the radical solution that you get rid of the extra edges by making the grating in a different way.

- Create a plane and subdivide it with six cuts.
- Create a circle that is slightly smaller than the plane.
- Go to top view.
- Select the circle and then the plane.
- In *Edit Mode* select Mesh->Knife Project
- Immediately switch to vertex select; invert the selection and delete the inversion.
- Add a wireframe modifier to the plane. Check boundary and set the thickness you want.
- Add a bevel modifier below it on the modifier stack.  Set the Amount appropriately and Segments to 2.  Make sure that the Bevel amount is less than half of the thickness in the wireframe.
- Add a subdivision surface last.

Here's the plane after all of the modifiers have been added:

[image: plane made into grid]

Here's the modifier stack for my example:

[image: modifier stack]

Now you can use the original circle to make the casing that surrounds the grid:

- Select the entire circle.
- Extrude and immediately hit accept.
- Scale outward to create the face of the casing.
- Extrude down to create the outside-
- Add a Bevel modifier
- Add a subdivision surface last.

[image: casing extruded the easy way]

If you want the casing to have thickness, extrude both the inside and outside circles.

Don't join the two, unless you apply the wireframe first.

Here's the result:

[image: grating with exterior casing]

Comment: Thanks.  Will try both tomorrow.

Comment: Tried both, they didn't do what I needed.  The second answer produced too many non-manifold edges for me.  Thanks anyhow.